# ARM: Disabling MMU and updating PC

Tags: linux, caching, assembly, arm, mmu

In short, I would like to shut down all MMU (and cache) operations in a Linux context (from inside the Kernel), for debug purposes, just to run some tests. To be perfectly clear, I don't intend that my system still be functional after that.

About my setup: I'm currently fiddling with a Freescale Vybrid (VF610) - which integrates a Cortex A5 - and its low power modes. Since I'm experimenting some *suspiciously local* memory corruption while the chip is in "Low Power Stop" mode and my DDR3 in self refresh, I'm trying to shift the operations bit by bit, and right now performing all the suspend/resume steps without actually executing the WFI. Since before this instruction I run with address translation, and after that without (it's essentially a reset), I would like to "simulate" that by "manually" shutting down the MMU.

(I *currently* have no JTAG nor any other debug access to my chip. I load it via MMC/TFTP/NFS, and debug it with LEDs.)

What I've tried so far:

```
    /* disable the Icache, Dcache and branch prediction */
    mrc     p15, 0, r6, c1, c0, 0
    ldr r7, =0x1804
    bic r6, r6, r7
    mcr     p15, 0, r6, c1, c0, 0
    isb

    /* disable the MMU and TEX */
    bic r7, r6, r7
    isb
    mcr p15, 0, r6, c1, c0, 0   @ turn on MMU, I-cache, etc
    mrc p15, 0, r6, c0, c0, 0   @ read id reg
    isb
    dsb
    dmb
```

and other variations to the same effect.

What I observe:

Before the MMU block, I can light a LED (3 assembly instructions, no branch, nothing fancy, nor any access to my DDR, which is already in self refresh - the virtual address for the GPIO port is stored in a register before that).

After the MMU block, I can no more, whether I try with physical or virtual addresses.

I think the problem may be related to my PC, which retains an outdated virtual address. Seeing how things are done elsewhere in the kernel, but the other way round (that is, while enabling translation) :

```
    ldr r3, =cpu_resume_after_mmu

    instr_sync
    mcr p15, 0, r0, c1, c0, 0   @ turn on MMU, I-cache, etc
    mrc p15, 0, r0, c0, c0, 0   @ read id reg
    instr_sync

    mov r0, r0
    mov r0, r0
    ret r3          @ jump to virtual address
ENDPROC(cpu_resume_mmu)
    .popsection
cpu_resume_after_mmu:
```

(from arch/arm/kernel/sleep.S, cpu_resume_mmu)

I wonder to what this 2 instructions delay is related to, and where it is documented. I've found nothing on the subject. I've tried something equivalent, without success:

```
    adr lr, BSYM(phys_block)

    /* disable the Icache, Dcache and branch prediction */
    mrc     p15, 0, r6, c1, c0, 0
    ldr r7, =0x1804
    bic r6, r6, r7
    mcr     p15, 0, r6, c1, c0, 0
    isb

    /* disable the MMU and TEX */
    bic r7, r6, r7
    isb
    mcr p15, 0, r6, c1, c0, 0   @ turn on MMU, I-cache, etc
    mrc p15, 0, r6, c0, c0, 0   @ read id reg
    isb
    dsb
    msb

    mov r0, r0
    mov r0, r0
    ret lr

phys_block:
    blue_light
    loop
```

Thanks to anyone who has a clue or some pointers!

Comment: Don't know much about ARM, but: once you disable the MMU, isn't it the case that the instruction pointer now refers to a physical address? If your code (i.e. the kernel code) is mapped to some virtual address, which seems likely, none of it that comes after disabling the MMU would run.

Comment: The problem is, I've found no mention of how the program counter behaves, or how we're supposed to manage it, on such an occasion. I deem it unlikely though  that it be automagically translated, and the Linux native code I've quoted (second code block above) seems to imply that it actually isn't, and that there's a precise number of instructions after MMU is launched, before virtual addresses are actually used and PC must be switched.

Comment: I usually map the memory at its physical address, jump on it, and then disable the MMU. A 1-to-1 mapping avoid such questions.

PS: an other idea may be to keep the I-cache for the current segment, disable MMU, jump to physical address (relying on I-cache) (cache at physical address shall be cleared) and then clear cache at previous location (or whole I-cache).

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't solve my problem, does it ? If I begin with remapping the memory to its physical address, that's when I won't know what to do with my PC. Except you can tell me when exactly you "jump on it" ?

Comment: You can map your instructions at 2 places at the same time: the address you are curretly running, and the physical address. This way you can branch to the physical address, running the same code, and disable the MMU

Comment: * s/Except/Unless/g :s

Comment: I wasn't aware of this possibility, thank you ! I will try that right now !

Comment: "and the Linux native code I've quoted (second code block above) seems to imply that it actually isn't, and that there's a precise number of instructions after MMU is launched, before virtual addresses are actually used and PC must be switched" - right, but that's (I assume) because of the _instruction cache_ (Icache), which you have disabled ;)

Comment: (or maybe the Icache is something different. In any case, processors normally have a small internal instruction cache, and for instance self-modifying code needs to take this into account, though you don't see much of that anymore...).

Comment: You're right in assuming the Icache is the instruction cache, but since (in this snippet) it is enabled at the same time as the MMU, I'm not sure it would allow the behaviour we're focused on. I think maybe there's an identity mapping somewhere for this bit of code to work. But that wouldn't be consistent with the Kernel mapping everything in the upper GB (0xcxxxxxxx, whereas ARM DDR is located at 0x8xxxxxxx), nor would it explain the need for two "mov r0, r0" (which is ARM for nop). It could be set up somewhere in suspend and wiped out during resume, I suppose.

Comment: Unless position independent your code and associated data (esp if alloced in some way) may rely on virtual addressing and you may not be able to simply switch to physical addressing.  the data esp if alloced may be small chunks spread all over made linear only in virtual space.   If the code you want to run after shutting stuff down is written for that then you need an mmu entry that maps the physical to virtual (caches disabled), jump to that, then shut things down and you remain in the same address space after the transition.

Comment: I'd suggest simply taking a look at [what `soft_restart()` does](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/kernel/process.c#L98).

Comment: @Jacen: I did exactly as you said, and after yet again some fiddling around (including learning table entries format and how ARM Linux manages them), it worked ! Thank you again. :)

Comment: @davmac: Following your suggestion, I tried to disable MMU first, then jump to a local physical address, then disable caches (especially the instructions one), but though the trick seemed perfectly nasty to me, it didn't work. ;)

Comment: @dwelch: Actually, both my code and my data reside in (the only chunk of) memory allocated from a genpool occupying the whole of VF610's internal RAM, so no risk of fragmentation. I was trying to do as you suggested (as had done Jacen), and it did the trick, thank you.

Comment: @Notlikethat: Unless I'm mistaken, soft_restart() doesn't touch MMU ?

Comment: `soft_restart()` -> `__soft_restart()` -> `setup_mm_for_reboot() ... cpu_reset(<your function here>)`. With all the other bits in the middle to take the core out of coherency without breaking things. AFAICT, all the code you want already exists.

Comment: My mistake, I seemingly forgot to follow through call_with_stack() to _soft_restart(). It does alter the MMU, although I can't see where the transition jump is made, and I don't think MMU is actually shut down (except as part of the final reset logic). Actually, what I see here is my original problem, occurring in another way (the mapping being instantly replaced with an identity one), and though the corresponding solution must accompany it, I can't seem to find it there. (Anyway, a whole identity mapping would be somewhat heavy handed, in my case.)

Comment: The relevant `cpu_reset()` implemetation for Cortex-A5 will be [the generic ARMv7 one in proc-v7.S](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mm/proc-v7.S#L54), which should be fairly self-explanatory, I hope ;) The idmap actually only covers the kernel text, but my point is really that it (and all the other infrastructure) already exists in Linux because Linux uses it on occasion, so something like `soft_restart(virt_to_phys(my_debug_function));` should just do everything for you.

Comment: Well, thank you. I actually referred to that implementation, but I'm prone to not parsing the comments, and on that occasion I fear I may have not parsed the code up to full understanding, either. Actually I'm reading my comments and the related code back, and I feel like I may have had gone too long without sleep...

Comment: virt_to_phys wouldn't do the trick here, but that's beside the point, which is : I'm not here to do, so much as to understand how it's done, and in that view I feel like the more generic pointers above are more helping. But I hope your kind indications will be of help to someone else. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both Jacen and dwelch kindly brought the answer I needed through a comment (each), I will answer my own question here for the sake of clarity:

The trick was simply to add an identity mapping from/to the page doing the transition, allowing us to jump to it with a "physical" (though actually virtual) PC, then disable MMU.

Here is the final code (a bit specific, but commented):

```
    /* Duplicate mapping to here */

    mrc p15, 0, r4, c2, c0, 0 // Get TTRB0
    ldr r10, =0x00003fff
    bic r4, r10 // Extract page table physical base address
    orr r4, #0xc0000000 // Nastily "translate" it to the virtual one

    /*
     * Here r8 holds vf_suspend's physical address. I had no way of
     * doing this more "locally", since both physical and virtual
     * space for my code are runtime-allocated.
     */

    add lr, r8, #(phys_block-vf_suspend) // -> phys_block physical address 

    lsr r9, lr, #20 // SECTION_SHIFT     -> Page index
    add r7, r4, r9, lsl #2 // PMD_ORDER  -> Entry address
    ldr r10, =0x00000c0e // Flags
    orr r9, r10, r9, lsl #20 // SECTION_SHIFT   -> Entry value
    str r9, [r7] // Write entry

    ret lr  // Jump / transition to virtual addressing

phys_block:
    /* disable the MMU and TEX */
    isb
    mrc     p15, 0, r6, c1, c0, 0
    ldr r7, =0x10000001
    bic r6, r6, r7
    mcr p15, 0, r6, c1, c0, 0   @ turn on MMU, I-cache, etc
    mrc p15, 0, r6, c0, c0, 0   @ read id reg
    isb
    dsb
    dmb

    /* disable the Icache, Dcache and branch prediction */
    mrc     p15, 0, r6, c1, c0, 0
    ldr r7, =0x1804
    bic r6, r6, r7
    mcr     p15, 0, r6, c1, c0, 0
    isb

    // Done !
```

Comment: There is one issue though. Caches have to be flushed before disabling MMU & named caches. Otherwise cached data are lost.

Comment: On the second thought, one more point. Caches should be disabled before (or together) MMU, not after.

Answer (score 2):

To address the "what this 2-instruction delay is" part of the question, as with much of /arch/arm, it's mostly just leftover legacy guff<sup>*</sup>.

Back in the days long before any kind of barrier instructions, you had to account for the fact that at the point you switch the MMU, the pipeline contains instructions already fetched and decoded before the switch, so having anything like a branch or memory access in there will go horribly wrong if the address space has changed by the time it executes. The ARMv4 Architecture Reference Manual makes the wonderful statement "The correct code sequence for enabling and disabling the MMU is IMPLEMENTATION DEFINED" - in practice what that mostly meant was that you knew your pipeline was 3 stages long so stuck two NOPs in to fill it safely. Or [took full advantage of the fact](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0229c/I282785.html) to do horrible things like arrange a jump straight to a translated VA without going via an identity mapping (yikes!).

From an entertaining trawl of old microarchitecture manuals, [3 NOPs are needed for StrongARM](http://netwinder.osuosl.org/pub/netwinder/docs/intel/manuals/278088.htm) (compared to 2 for the 3-stage ARM7 pipeline), and reading CP15 with a data dependency on the result is the recommended self-synchronising sequence for [XScale](http://spazioinwind.libero.it/inginfotv/appunti/ae1/PXA255%20Processor%20User%20Manual.pdf), which explains the apparently pointless read of the main ID register.

On something modern (ARMv6 or later), however, none of this should be needed as you have architected barriers, so you just flip the switch then issue an `isb` to flush the pipeline, which is what the `instr_sync` macro expands to when building for such architectures.

<sub>* or a fine example of the Linux "works on everything" approach, depending on your point of view...</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the history lesson. :) I wondered about the ID register read, too, which appears at other similar occasions in the initialization code.