# How to turn off MMU and access physical address directly on ARM?

Tags: c++, arm, memory-address

I am trying to modify Genode OS for ARM and have the physical address of an instruction pointer. I want to read the physical address but am unable to get the corresponding virtual address to dereference programmatically. How can I switch off MMU temporarily and access that phys address? I am not very familiar with ARM assembly, so any assembly code will be helpful.

Codebase is in C++ and I am using GNU compiler on a linux machine.

Comment: If you turn off the MMU then all code is suddenly running at the wrong address. Might be better to just map the physical address to a VA in your process.

Comment: Why do you want to run with the MMU off?  You can not use the cache if you do this.  There are questions on getting the physical address of a virtual for use with DMA...  What is the underlying reason?  I think [Disable MMU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843270/arm-disabling-mmu-and-updating-pc) question answers directly; you need assembler and specific depend on the ARM CPU in use.