# How to create 1:1 MMU mapping in ARM64 Linux?

Tags: linux, virtual-memory, arm64, mmu

I'm trying to switch off MMU to run some test code. I need to create exactly 1:1 virtual to physical memory mapping for code to run after MMU turned off.

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843270/arm-disabling-mmu-and-updating-pc) a guy described a method to create such a mapping with assembly code, but it seems like by the time he creates mapping, system is unfunctional.

My question is:

- Is it possible to create a 1:1 MMU mapping, leaving linux functional (to test mapping and to load test code with devmem file)?
- If possible, what is the best option to create it?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to create exactly 1:1 virtual to physical memory mapping for
> code to run after MMU turned off

That simply does not make sense. Memory mapping is used only when MMU is **ON**.

Once MMU is off there is no virtual-to-physical translations and memory is access by physical addresses. Well in such way it could be described as '1:1 virtual to physical'.

Problem with switching off MMU is that code which does that should be specially build to run with that 1:1 mapping.

For example code is build to call function with **virtual** address `0x8000`. OS is placing you program at **physical** address `0x00C0_0000`. So basically jump into `0x8000` is jumping to physical `0x00C0_8000`. 
Once MMU is off, jump into `0x8000` would be into physical `0x8000`.

Additionally, make sure that caches are flushed before turning MMU off.